# VS Code Extensions - Propagate Captured Key Binding

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a custom extension I want to add a command to the 'tab' key.  However, I don't want to stop the 'tab' key from doing its regular duties.

So if I capture the 'tab' key how can I then "bubble" this event?  My `package.json` looks like this:

```
"contributes": {
    ...
    "commands": [
            {
                "command": "command_name"
                ...
            }
        ],
        "keybindings": [
            {
                "command": "command_name",
                "key": "tab",
                "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
            }   
        ]
}
```

This currently captures the 'tab' character but breaks auto-complete, insertion of the tab character, etc.  I can of course manually insert a \t into the editor in my command, but that still leaves auto-complete broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `"tab"` with quotes inside Keyboard Shortcuts to see all <kbd>Tab</kbd> bindings. Among them you'll find `When` contexts in which it is used.

To exclude context put a `!` before it. Exclude all needed for your extension. Like that:

```json
"when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !suggestWidgetVisible && !inSnippetMode"// ...
```

Comment: Great, I ended up with this: `"when": "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible && !editorTabMovesFocus && !inSnippetMode && !hasSnippetCompletions && !editorTabMovesFocus && !editorReadonly"`